# Waterline: Sum/Avg/Mix/Max of populated values in waterline

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

Please see the example:

User Object:

```
{ 
    name: 'Mike',
    age: 16,
    createdAt: Wed Feb 12 2014 18:06:50 GMT-0600 (CST),
    updatedAt: Wed Feb 12 2014 19:30:54 GMT-0600 (CST),
    id: 7 
}
```

Pet Objects associated with the user Mike

```
{
    name: 'Scooby',
    color: 'pink',
    petAge: 2
    id: 1,
    createdAt: Wed Feb 12 2014 18:06:50 GMT-0600 (CST),
    updatedAt: Wed Feb 12 2014 18:06:50 GMT-0600 (CST) 
}

{
    name: 'Alpha',
    color: 'red',
    petAge: 5
    id: 2,
    createdAt: Wed Feb 12 2014 18:16:50 GMT-0600 (CST),
    updatedAt: Wed Feb 12 2014 18:16:50 GMT-0600 (CST) 
}
```

I want to get sum of 'petAge' for pets of Mike. I was trying the below query, but it did not work.

```
User.find({name:'Mike'})
.populate('pets')
.sum('pets.petAge')
.exec(function(e,r){

});
```

I want to understand if getting sum of `petAge` is possible or not. (`sum('pets.petAge')`).

Comment: Try `sum('petAge')` . It should work, because after populating `pets`, you would have array of pets having `petAge` as property.

Comment: @MukeshSharma, just tried. That is not working.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the sum function on the Pets model like this.

```
Pets.sum('petAge').where({user: "UserID"}).exec(function (e,r) {
//do what you want here
});
```

here UserID is the id of the user.